# Is it possible to post the data from an HTML table to another PHP page?

Tags: php, html

This is my first question on S.O so apologies if this is done incorrectly however I'm stumped as to whether this is even possible let alone how to do it.  I have a form and within that form is a dynamically generated table.  The user adds defects to a table if they are still outstanding.  So the amount of rows will vary every use.

```
<table class="mytable" id="open-defect-table" name="open-defect-table">
    <tr>
        <th name="example">Defect ID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Severity</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Assigned To</th>
        <th>Defect Link</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above is the table that sits on the page normally and whenever the user clicks a button:

```
<input type="button" name="open-defect-add-button" id="open-defect-add-button" value="Add" onclick="addOpenDefect()">
```

It adds the details to the table and provides a unique ID to the row.

However I'm not sure how I then go about posting on the form submit to another page..in my case "export.php"

Within the PHP page is this:

```
<h2>Open Defects: <span>
    <?php 
    $selected_option = $_POST["open-defects-select"];
    if ($selected_option == "Yes"){
        // What i'm trying to work out
    } else {
        echo ("None"); 
    }
    ?></span></h2>
```

Within that field I want to copy the table that was created within the previous form.

Is this possible? And if so how would I go about or what would be the best way in tackling this?

Any help would be appreciated and again apologies if anything is missing from the details.

Comment: So, in your `addOpenDefect()` function, you can send a POST to your php page using jquery, for example. Google `jQuery post`

Comment: Note that it would be a bad idea to submit data you retrieved from your site.  It would make much more sense to specify what the user chose.

Comment: Ryan, there are two answers to your question. If any answer is useful for you, you can click its checkmark to accept it (this is how you reward people for their effort).

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help, I really appreciate it! Thanks for the heads up @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez will bear that in mind in the future! You're all life savers :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a name to each cell on the table, for example, if you have a table with names and phones, all the cells in the column "name" will share the name "name", and all the cells in the column "phone" will share the name "phone". Notice all the cells share the same names, when this happens, they become an array, so, you will have an array of names and another array of phones. Example code:

**zzz.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function add_row ()
{ var tbl = document.getElementById( "tbl" );
  var row = tbl.insertRow( -1 ); // INSERT ROW AT THE END OF TABLE.
  var cel = row.insertCell( -1 ); // INSERT CELL AT THE END OF ROW.
      cel.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='name[]'/>";    // ◄■■■ [] ARRAY.
  cel = row.insertCell( -1 ); // REUSING THE SAME VARIABLE.
  cel.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='phone[]'/>";       // ◄■■■ [] ARRAY.
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="add_row()">Add row</button>
    <form method="post" action="zzz.php">
      <table id="tbl" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Phone</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**zzz.php**

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST["name"] ) && isset( $_POST["phone"] ) )
     { echo "Names: <br/>";
       foreach ( $_POST["name"] as $name ) // $_POST["name"] IS AN ARRAY.
         echo $name . "<br/>";

       echo "<br/><br/>" .
            "Phones: <br/>";
       foreach ( $_POST["phone"] as $phone ) // $_POST["phone"] IS AN ARRAY.
         echo $phone . "<br/>";
     }
else echo "Error: no data";
?>
```

Copy-paste previous codes in files with the given names (zzz.html, zzz.php), then open zzz.html in your browser. Click several times the button "Add row", type some data, then click "Submit". PHP will get the names and phones as arrays and display their contents.

The important thing here is the use of `[]` :

```
cel.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='name[]'/>";    // ◄■■■ [] ARRAY.
```

All the `<input`s named "name[]" will become an array and will be submitted as an array.

The idea is to send the whole table as arrays, one array per column. On the PHP side, you are getting the table's data as arrays, you will be able to re-build the entire table again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery post for this purpose

```
var data = {
    key1: "value1",
    key2: "value2",
    key3: "value3"
};

$.post( "ajax/openDefects.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

see [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) official documentation for more details.